# Can I run nodetool cleanup while nodetool repair is running?

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-2.1

I have couple of questions.

1. Can I run nodetool cleanup while nodetool repair is running? Our scheduled crons are running "nodetool repair -pr" command on servers. These repair takes days to finish. I have just finished adding up new server. And I want to run "nodetool cleanup" command. Is it ok to run this command while "nodetool repair -pr" command is running?
2. Is it Ok to run "nodetool cleanup" command on multiple servers at same time?
3. Is it ok to run "nodetool repair -pr" command on multiple servers at the same time?

Cassnadra versions are 2.1 and 1.2.

Comment: check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38249206/simultaneous-repairs-cause-repair-to-hang and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30544834/cassandra-cleanup-on-several-servers-at-once

Answer (score 1):

Cleanup run separately do not involve other nodes so it is completely safe to run in parallel. but, you should run it one at once to reduce the performance impact because it may cause high disk I/O.

Repair with -pr reduces overhead on other nodes but still want them to send merkle tree and can make them little busy and can reduce performance if runs in parallel. This too should be run in sequence to deal with high I/O and remove latencies.

Comment: Thanks Payal!. What if I do not care about  high I/O or latencies? In that case, can I run "nodetool repair -pr" on all (or many) nodes at the same time?

Comment: In that case you can run it.  However it may cause whole cluster performance degrade.